# Selenium RC- Print all links that contains a text

Tags: java, xpath, selenium

I want a selenium RC java test script that prints all the links in a page which contains `show/id`.

I tried this

```
int servicecount= selenium.getXpathCount("xpath=//a[contains(@href,'show/id')]").intValue();
for(int servicecnt=1;servicecnt<=servicecount;servicecnt++)
{
  String some_container=selenium.getText("xpath= //a[contains(@href,'show/id')["+servicecnt+"]");
  System.out.println(some_container);
}
```

This doesn't work. Please suggest solutions.

Comment: Can you please post some example link? And what do you mean by doesn't work?

Comment: "This does not work" ... What error are you getting?

Comment: Thanks for the replies.. Sample link: https://control.crucial.com.au/myservices/show/id/8160 and the error  19:43:47.068 INFO - Command request: getText[xpath= //a[contains(@href,'show/id')[1], ] on session b0ba523c7d48455e8798b70d3dc5b1fc
19:43:48.227 INFO - Got result: ERROR: Invalid xpath [2]:  //a[contains(@href,'show/id')[1] on session b0ba523c7d48455e8798b70d3dc5b1fc
FAILED: virtualserverCheck

Comment: Th selenium.getText("xpath=(//a)["+servicecnt+"]") works but I want the links which contains 'show/id' only..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev),

> **NOTE:** The location path `//para[1]` does not mean the same as the
>   location path `/descendant::para[1]`. The latter selects the first
>   descendant `para` element; the former selects all descendant `para`
>   elements that are the first `para` children of their parents.

That means that you need to use the latter approach:

```
selenium.getText("xpath=/descendant::input[contains(@href,'show/id')]["+servicecnt+"]");
```

Comment: Hi.. It still gives me the error, 19:47:32.886 INFO - Command request: getText[xpath=//a[contains(@href,'show/id')][2], ] on session 90d7089a9556482fad3f09dc0e347fb4
19:47:33.931 INFO - Got result: ERROR: Element xpath=//a[contains(@href,'show/id')][2] not found on session 90d7089a9556482fad3f09dc0e347fb4
FAILED:

Comment: @ShariHaridas Aha! Sorry, my mistake. I only saw the syntax error and didn't think any further. Now I edited my answer with a good solution.